# How to install cinterop tool in Windows/Ubuntu

Tags: c, kotlin, installation, kotlin-native, cinterop

I am following this tutoriel to use C library in Kotlin (Android Studio)  https://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2018/05/28/minimalistic-kn/ But I can’t find the how to install/download the cinterop tool both in Windows and Ubuntu I have the error “cinterop: command not found” ! Does anybody please knows how to install cinterop ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This tool is a part of the `kotlin-native` distribution, and it does not make any sense to use it without the Kotlin/Native compiler. So, in fact, you would like to get all the distribution here, and install it correctly.

There are three main approaches to the Kotlin/Native installation. All of them are described in the documentation.

- [Installing it with the IntelliJ IDEA](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-get-started.html). You should just get an IDE and let it install everything on its own. It will download all tools and put them to the following location: `~/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-<osName>-<kotlinVersion>/bin/`. Then you will be able to add this folder to your `PATH` and call the tool from CLI.
- [Installing using the Gradle build system](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-gradle.html). Quite similar, but this one will require manual installation of the Gradle. The first run will also download all tools and pack them to the same location as in the IDE case.
- [Installing the CLI tool](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-command-line-compiler.html). This looks like the most appropriate way to follow the tutorial, but won't help a lot when you start working on more sophisticated projects. In general, you should just download the latest version of the Kotlin/Native, unpack it to some folder and add this folder to your `PATH`.